# Playwright: Stop if http status is 500

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

I would like playwright to fail early, and stop as soon as one http request is not `200` or `302`.

```
def test_it(live_server):
    os.environ['DEBUG']='pw:api'
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        run_test_id(live_server, playwright)

def run_test_id(live_server, playwright):
    browser = playwright.webkit.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto(live_server.url)
    page.click("text=Create Test Data")
```

Unfortunately `page.click()` returns None, so I have no clue how I can check for the http status of the click.

How could I implement "Fail on unusual http status" in Playwright?

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use [`page.on()`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page?_highlight=page.on#pageonresponse):

```py
def handle_response(response):
    print(f"{response.status}")
    if response.status == 500:
        exit(1)

page.on("response", handle_response)
```

This, however, doesn't check for only a status code after the click, but for any response for a request, so for example if your `page.goto()` returns 500, it will stop here as well.

(I'm more used to Playwright with JS, so my example might be a tiny bit off.)

Comment: Thank you, your answers helps. In my whole test-suite, I never want a http 500 to appear.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about Python but this came up for me while I was searching for a solution for Playwright in Node.js, so I am leaving this here for future people in the same position.

This will cause the test to fail on a 500 status, and print the failed URL.

```
test.beforeEach(async function({page}) {
  page.on("response", async (response) => {
    if (response.status() === 500) {
      await expect(response.url()).toBe('This URL responded with a 500 status');
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with [pavelsaman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66716555) causing pytest to hang on the exit, so here's a slightly different solution that doesn't use `exit()`:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import Page

def handle_response(response):
    assert response.status in [200, 302], f"Status code {response.status}"

def test_home_page(page: Page):
    page.on("response", handle_response) # any error from this point on will trigger the handler
    page.goto("https://www.google.com")
```

As a bonus, this approach allows you to add a custom error message. In my example I just print the status code, but you can add more complex messages if desired.

Example usage:

```
$ pytest
============================== short test summary info ==============================
ERROR test_website.py::test_home_page[chromium] - AssertionError: Status code 500
```